# How to allow local storage for one specific userscript, but disable it globally?

Tags: firefox, userscripts, local-storage

I'm using Firefox 10.0 with Greasemonkey 0.9.15. I want to use a userscript, that requires access to local storage. I don't want local storage to be allowed globally.

Is there a way to achieve this goal without modifying userscript?

If userscript modification is necessary, what can I use as the replacement for local storage?

Answer (score 1):

The Greasemonkey equivalent of `localStorage` are the [GM_getValue](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_getValue) and [GM_setValue](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_setValue) functions. Just be aware that for example the contemporary Chrome implementation of userscripts doesn't support these (among other things) and if you want your userscripts to work cross-browser, you'll still have to write a fallback function using `localStorage`.